# How to call a callback from a response from cURL with a json API?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to implement an API from an external service and I'm working with their staging environment. At the moment I'm working with some test data to make a basic request/response to work.

I'm using php and the `cURL` library. 
These are the data for the request:

```
$post_data = array(
    'some_property' => array(
        'key1' => 'value'
     ),
    'some_other_property' => array(...),
    'sandbox' => array(
        'api_key' => 'my_api',
        'callbacks' => array(
            'callback-type-1' => array('url' => 'http://my-url.local/api/callback1'),
            'callback-type-2' => array('url' => 'http://my-url.local/api/callback2')
         )
    )
)
```

And the curl part:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: my_auth_key',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'X-Environment: sandbox'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post_data)
    )
);
```

In the `$post_data` array there is a `sandbox` property which is used to test the callback mechanism, so, if the request is successfull, the callbacks listed in `sandbox/callbacks` should be called.
What happens is that the first request is successfull, but then it fails to call the callback function. 
Printing the response I receive this error:

```
[sandbox] => Array
        (
            [callback-type-1] => Callback could not be sent (Exception: Unable to Connect to tcp://my-url.local/:80. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
        )
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with cURL but searcing around I didn't really understand what.

Comment: Usually a "getaddrinfo failed" error means that you're unable to resolve the hostname to an ip address. Are you able to ping "http://my-url.local"? If the url exists but it's not resolved by your dns you may need to add the entry to your hosts file. Imho, since it seems like a placeholder for a real url you may want to edit it with the correct value or simply put a "127.0.0.1 my-url.local " entry in the hosts file to loopback.

Comment: If the API provider is the one trying to issue the callback (from their sandbox), it stands to reason that in `their` environment, the host name `my-url.local` canot be resolved (probably your development environment). If it is the case, you need to setup a matching sandbox, with a public name and address, to carry out that test.